# Meaning of *iuvenis*

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, adjective

I seem to remember reading that *iuvenis* referred to someone roughly between 15 and 30. However, my Collins Latin Dictionary states it refers to someone between 30 and 45. Since a man could serve as praetor or consul at around the 40 year old mark, this seems highly unlikely. Even today, I doubt if a 44-year-old would be considered "young", except perhaps by an octogenarian! Have Collins got it wrong? Sorry if this is a bit basic, so is my Latin at present.

Comment: Reminds me of the song [Gaudeamus igitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaudeamus_igitur)

Comment: There is an overlap of social use and literal use: e.g. *infans* in law means under 18; *infans* in daily use means younger than *puer.*  Hence a king with a white beard is *"Iuvenis"* in the spandrel of MS Arundel 83 126v; juxtaposed with *iuvenis* in sequence between *adolescens* and *vir quasi rex* (circa 1310)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Others pointed out the dictionary definition of *iuvenis*, but it would help to have a solid example. In Livy book 21.50, Ti. Sempronius met with Hiero at Syracuse.

> statum deinde insulae et Carthaginiensium conata exposuit pollicitusque est, quo animo priore bello populum Romanum **iuvenis** adiuvisset, eo **senem** adiuturum; frumentum vestimentaque sese legionibus consulis sociisque navalibus gratis praeliturum; grande periculum Lilybaeo maritimisque civitatibus esse, et quibusdam volentibus novas res fore.
>
> He then described conditions in the island and the attempts made by the Carthaginians, and promised that with the same spirit with which, in his youth, he had helped the Roman People in the former war he would help them now, as an old man, and would furnish corn and clothing gratis to the legions of the consul and the naval allies.

We don't know exactly when Hiero was born, but it was at least 307. The war in which he was talking about was in 264, when, according to Dio Cassius (fr. Vat. 57) and Zonarius (8.6), he helped the Romans to the chagrin of the Carthaginians during the First Punic War. This would have made him a forty-three year old *iuvenis*.

Livy ([24.4](http://mcadams.posc.mu.edu/txt/ah/Livy/Livy24.html#livy.hist.24.4)) also knew how old he was, as he said he was 90 when he died in 215. Even if he was off a few years, that still puts him in or near the 40s as a *iuvenis*.

Comment: Excellent! This addresses the point that is actually contentious.

Comment: @CMWeimer Thank you for that. I suspect the problem lies in the etymological link between *iuvenis* and the English *juvenile* which is actually closer to *adulescens* - English at least does not have a word for someone in the "prime of life". And if, as Cerberus suggests,it was mainly applied to men,   may it not have had connotations of strength, experience etc, rather than simply "youth"? Or am I barking up the wrong etymological tree?

Comment: Good find! One thing to consider is that Livy wrote several centuries after Hero's birth. Did he know how old Hiero was exactly at the time in question?

Comment: @TheHonRose There's also the adjective *iuvenis*, which really does mean "youth," but from what I understand the noun had become codified as a particular age set.

Comment: @Cerberus Good point! He does, and I added a paragraph to address that.

Comment: Excellent! No doubt the Oxford and others base their age ranges on sources such as this.

Comment: One slight doubt: does *iuvenis* only work here because it is juxtaposed with *senis*, almost like "younger" vs. "older"?

Comment: @brianpck Undoubtedly more sources are needed, and I can keep gathering sources when I have more time, but were it simply the case of contrast, I suspect we would have seen *iunior*. Note that in Polybius, Hiero in his thirties is called *neon*.

Answer (score 9):

From Lewis and Short:

> Subst.: **jŭvĕnis**, is, comm., *one who is in the flower of his or her age* (mostly of persons older than adolescentes and younger than seniores, i.e. between twenty and forty years)

Lewis' *Elementary Latin Dictionary* says the same:

> As subst m. and f *one in the flower of age, a young person, youth* (i.e. between twenty and forty years)

These are the only two I've found which mention specific ages, but other dictionaries imply an age closer to 20 than 40 as well.

Comment: I'm glad to hear I'm still in my youth. I was starting to think otherwise.

Comment: Well, I'm definitely *senex*, but 'prime of life', as I read L&S *flower* seems more reasonable!

Answer (score 7):

A *iuvenis* was probably between the ages of the earliest adulthood and early forties, although the word could also be used more casually for anyone who was "youngish".

The Oxford Latin Dictionary (1968) has the following:

> A young man, youth (technically, any adult male up to the age of 45)

I'm not entirely sure what they mean by *technically*, but presumably the Romans made a distinction between casual use (any youngish man) and more precise or even legal use. Unfortunately, no source is mentioned, nor is one obvious from the quotations.

Lewis & Short say this:

> one who is in the flower of his or her age (mostly of persons older than *adolescentes* and younger than *seniores*, i. e. between twenty and forty years), a young person, a young man, a young woman

They do not mention any source either, but they seem less positive about the specific limits than the Oxford does. In addition, I think a iuvenis is normally a man; women are probably far less frequently so called.

Comment: I think it would be really helpful to find a classical usage of *iuvenis* for someone on the higher end of that spectrum.

Comment: @brianpck Done.